# Does Spring cloud task handle auto closing of the Kubernetes pods when the worker node has completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, aws-batch, spring-cloud-task

I am writing the Spring batch app on AWS cloud and in order to ensure efficient utilization of resource , I had this question that "Does Spring cloud task handle auto closing of the Kubernetes pods when the worker node has completed".

If any one can answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The K8s deployer for SCDF delegates all lifecycle operations to K8s, using a plain pod or optionally a job. Upon completion, the pod terminates but is not deleted. The most recent release of SCDF may delete the pods as part of a task cleanup action that you run as needed using the UI, but I’m not sure about this. If not, it’s fairly easy to do via `kubectl delete` selecting all pods that have a `task-name` label.